# Apache Axis2 Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the service project Test

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

Apache Axis2 Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the service project Test. Why? Please help me

Comment: Would be great if you accept my answer as solution, if it worked for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 55):

I just had the same issue. It turns out that Axis2 doesn't like the 3.0 dynamic web projects of Eclipse. 
Just create a new dynamic web project and choose "Dynamic Web Module Version" to be below 3.0, i.e. 2.5, 2.4.
I used the 2.5 version and now everything works like a charm.

Trying to change the version from the "Project Facets" in Preferences does not work :( so a new project must be made.

Good luck!

Comment: With the current version of eclipse juno (06 May 2013), you can simply change the facet, downgrading it to 2.5

Comment: +1 solving my problem. Now i have to deal with some kind of "Selection must be WSDL" error when i create a webservice.

Comment: I was unable to downgrade from 3.0 to 2.5 in Project Facets in Eclipse Luna. Eclipse was throwing error.  In project explorer expand your project. > .settings > org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml         Right Click it and edit      <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/> to    <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error like "**The Tomcat v5.5 Server server does not support the service project xxxxx**". I tried changing the version as 2.5 it also didnt workout for me. 
The solution is to add a new latest version server in the eclipse (Tomcat 7.0) and it worked for me.