# Error in Creating web-service client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have created one webservice for accessing database.it's working fine .but when i am trying to creat client from that using it's WSDL it's giving error as

```
    "The Apache Axis2 Web service runtime does not support the client project"
```

I am using tomcat 6.0 and Axis2 .for creating client i have created java project and then trying to create client .SO I'm not getting why this error is getting .for axis2 does the client project is to be Dynamic web project??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You should create new "Dynamic Web Project". In the project wizard you should change "Dynamic web module version" from 3 to lower(2.2, 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5). In my case it worked with 2.5. Then you can finish creating project and generate web service client.

Comment: The same solution documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674363/apache-axis2-web-service-runtime-in-tomcat-v7-0-server-does-not-support-the-serv